# BindingSource, set datasource and then set a NEW datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I've got a BindingSource with only 1 object as the DataSource.

I bind on some values on the datasource. That works perfectly.

BUT.

When I do:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = new Foo () { Bar = "..."; }
```

this is not reflected through the UI.

is there a way to force an update?

I tried resetbindings on the controls that bind to the datasource but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried calling `ResetBindings()` on the `BindingSource` instead?